# Inserting a giving key into its correct place in sorted order in a linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, sortedlist

The list has 4,6,10,17
after insert(head,8)
List has to become 4,6,8,10,17

I have been given these definitions;

```
struct ListNode{
    int key; 
    struct ListNode *next;
}

struct ListHead *insert(struct ListHead *head, int key){
```

Are the definitions correct? Shouldn't be there is an int data; instead of int key; in the definitions?

So far I wrote this code;
by changing the

```
struct ListNode{
    int key; 
    struct ListNode *next;
}
```

to

```
struct ListNode{
    int data; 
    struct ListNode *next;
}
```

```
struct ListHead *insert(struct ListHead *head, int key){
    ListHead* current;
    if(*head == NULL ||(*head)->key >= key>data){
        key->next = *head;
        *head = key;
}
    else {
    current = *head;
    while(current->next!=NULL && current->next->data < key->data){
        current = current->next;
    }
    key->next = current->next;
    current->next = key;
}
```

Am I wrong on this?

Comment: Why a linked list? That's close to the most *inefficient* data structure you could pick on contemporary machines.. unless you *need* the guarantee that objects won't move in memory, a `std::vector` is probably a better choice.

Comment: "data" and "key" are just names. They don’t actually mean anything, and changing them does nothing. Implementing insert is most straightforwardly done with double pointers: you want to compute a pointer to the pointer to the node after the insertion point.

Comment: What does your compiler tell you about your code?